# Disabling Price Ranges on Bundle Items

Tags: magento, php

I am working on my first website hosted on Magento, and am having a problem with my bundle items.  I am using a bundle item to allow users to select upgrades to the materials for their products, and it is not required so they can leave the stock material.

The problem is that the product on the frontend displays a price range for between the lowest material upgrade and the highest.  Is there a way to stop that from the displaying?

I figured out how to change it to display an "As Low As" price, but I want it gone completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit the following file, you can change the way that bundle prices are displayed:

```
DOCROOT\app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\template\bundle\catalog\product\price.phtml
```

There some complex logic in there to cope with price ranges, "As low as", tax and other considerations, but you should be able to work your way through it.

Make sure that you edit the version of this file that is in your theme (if it only exists in `base/default` then copy it to the same path under `default/yourtheme`).

Cheers,
JD

Comment: Thanks.  I am having a friend who knows PHP better than me look at the file, because I don't understand a lot of what is really going on.  I found the if statements, but I am confused as to how those statements are working.  I am usually a CF guy, but needed a robust store really quick so I went with Magento.